# Draw a polygon in OpenLayers with coordinates from a variable?

Tags: polygon, javascript, openlayers

I have the polygon coordinates defined as a variable. This draws nothing when I use the variable, when the same coordinates are used as such in the `polygonFeatureT` definition, the polygon is drawn correctly.

With point coordinates as variable this works, provided that the quotes are not used.

What am I doing wrong here?

The code is below:

```
var polyCoords = '[3143090.603086447, 9928281.393790578], [3283734.7351311715, 9928892.890016861], [3181003.3691158947, 9849398.380600277], [3143090.603086447, 9928281.393790578]';

// this Point var works only when no quotes are used in definiton!
var pointCoords = [3229617.319105267, 9916160.39109719];

var polygonFeatureT = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Polygon([[polyCoords]]));
var pointFeatureK = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(pointCoords));

var map = new ol.Map({

        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
               new ol.layer.Vector({
                   source: new ol.source.Vector({
                       features: [polygonFeatureT, pointFeatureK]
                   }),
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is a string you will need add any extra `[]` then convert it into an array of coordinates

```
var polyCoords = '[3143090.603086447, 9928281.393790578], [3283734.7351311715, 9928892.890016861], [3181003.3691158947, 9849398.380600277], [3143090.603086447, 9928281.393790578]';
var pointCoords = '[3229617.319105267, 9916160.39109719]';

var polygonFeatureT = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Polygon(JSON.parse('[[' + polyCoords + ']]')));
var pointFeatureK = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(JSON.parse(pointCoords)));
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much - this worked and you saved my day!

Comment: @ArtoVitikka It would be appropriate then that you mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for noticing me on this - first time around!